# Oracle query to PostgreSQL conversion

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

Could you please help with some converted Oracle queries to postgreSQL queries, it is exists?

I have an Oracle query which I want to adopt for postgreSQL, could you please help me with this?

```
merge into TABLE_NAME using dual on 
(ID='CF9EB9FE6F6D4CC9B75EC0CD420421B91541944569' and ANOTHER_ID='E198D55909D94895AF747ED7E032AC58') 
when matched then update set USER='USERNAME' 
when not matched then insert values('EEA2620A4A0F31CE05E69B','CFB75EC0CD41B91541944569','E198D55909D94895AF747ED7E032AC58','USERNAME',null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the `upsert` in Postgres using [`insert . . . on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html):

```
insert into table_name (?, id, anotherid, ?, ?)   -- put in the column names
    values('EEA2620A4A0F31CE05E69B', 
           'CFB75EC0CD41B91541944569', 
           'E198D55909D94895AF747ED7E032AC58',
           'USERNAME', null
          )
    on conflict (id, anotherid)
    do update set USER = 'USERNAME';
```

You want a unique constraint on `(id, anotherid)` so the conflict is recognized:

```
alter table table_name add constraint unq_tablename_id_anotherid unique (id, anotherid);
```

The unique constraint needs to be defined on the columns that would cause the conflict.

Comment: I am receiving now ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Comment: @liotur - so do you have a unique constraint defined on your target table?

Comment: Yes I have, lets call it OID.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I don't want to change something in the tables and columns. I have something that works in Oracle, and I need to convert it to postgreSQL. Is there way to do it without changing the key?

Comment: @liotur . . . Adding a unique constraint on a pair of columns that should be unique does not seem like "changing" the tables.  In any case, that is how upsert works in Postgres.  Your alternative is using separate `update` and `insert` statements within a single transaction.

Comment: Yep it worked with unique constraint. However now i understand that I can't defined unique constrain for these columns. How can I do it in two queries?